# Problem with FCM (Firebase Notifications) and multiple APNS tokens from the same app

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

When using FCM app registers APNS token via `Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(pushToken, type: .prod)`

This method correlates APNS token with FCM token so later when FCM token is used for sending push notification the notification is delivered to registered APNS token.

**How to deal with multiple tokens situation?**
In some situations there might be different tokens for different types of push notifications.

One of possible examples is [Location Push](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/creating_a_location_push_service_extension).
For registering to Location Push notifications there is a dedicated method `startMonitoringLocationPushes(completion:)` which returns completely different APNS token. This token must be used for push notifications of type `location`.
For other notifications (like `alert` or `background`) the regular token is used which is acquired in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`.

**FCM method `.setAPNSToken` overwrites the previous value so it can save only one token indeed.**

Now I have a backend service which needs to send Location Push in one case and a regular one (with visual text) in different case.
The backend uses FCM so it uses FCM token which is one, single.

Example of the problem:

1. app registers APNS token for regular push notification via FCM library method
2. app registers Location Push token via FCM library method (this overwrites token from p1)
3. backend sends a location push to FCM token. it works OK.
4. backend sends a regular push with text. it does not work: wrong token. (Firebase tried to send regular push using location-push token which is incompatible)

I don't see the option to have both tokens added and use them for sending various notifications types.
**But maybe there is a solution?** Any tips appreciated.

Comment: I guess the only solution as of now is to handle location push differently in the backend unfortunately